# Как запустить код на си на андройд

Tags: android, c

Ребят, задался целью сделать свой первый самостоятельный небольшой проект на языке си, сделать мессенджер в терминале, на линукс и винду я понимаю как это сделать, но как сделать так, чтобы этот чат работал в терминале на андройд, объясните пожалуйста что мне подучить, может есть какие-то библиотеки на андройд, а может вообще код написанный для линукса будет работать на андройд(он же построен на ядре линукса)?. Буду очень признателен за ответы.

Comment: Я делал так. Писал программу для консоли и компилировал компилятором gcc-7-arm-linux-gnueabi и запускал в adb консоли и всё работало. Правда там ограничения в android, пришлось root права получить, чтобы был доступ ко всей файловой системе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тебе нужно будет в первую очередь установиться взаимодействие с с++, для этого  смотри JNI, тебе очень поможет библиотека djinni.
По сути ты создаешь методы jni, которые в какой то мере делают оболочку для C++. Djinni автоматически их генерит. Тебе все го лишь нужно будет в Java их применить. Тебе так же нужно будет в файлаъ Application и Android .mk указать параметры для работы с с++ и пути на либы .so